# Retrieve only 1 dataset out of many dataset in Firebase

Tags: json, rest, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I would like to retrieve 1 dataset out of, example, 3 datasets in Firebase. I am using Firebase RESTful api to do that.

I tried using parameters but I kept getting all 3 datasets instead of 1.

```
https://mydatabase.firebaseio.com/user.json?Name=Alan
```

This is how my data looks like in JSon

```
{
     "1234567": {
          "Name": "Alan",
          "Department": "Retail Team"
     },
     "7894563": {
          "Name": "Joe",
          "Department": "Sales Team"
     },
     "9876543": {
          "Name": "Tammy",
          "Department": "Customer Service"
     }
}
```

Comment: This is explained in [the docs about filtering](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/retrieve-data#section-rest-filtering)

Comment: @AndréKool I read this doc, i tried the simple one (with the example shown in the question area). I tried with the `Name` parameter but it didn't work

Comment: No offence but it doesn't look like you have tried it. The example in your question doesn't include `orderBy ` and `equalTo` as shown in the docs.

Comment: @AndréKool No offence taken, however, the filtering part is when I need it to be in certain order, example `Height` as given in that doc example. But as for now, I just need to retrieve by `Name`. The rest of the doc talks about complex filtering which I won't be needing it yet.

Comment: I think your reading it wrong but lets not discuss that. Can you try this: `https://mydatabase.firebaseio.com/user.json?orderBy="Name"&equalTo="Alan"`?

Comment: @AndréKool My apologies if I make any mistake, I am relatively new to NoSQL & Firebase... Anyway, I have tried what you have mentioned and I got any error on `"Index not defined, add \".indexOn\": \"Name\", for path \"/user\", to the rules"`

Comment: @AndréKool Solved the error already by adding rules in my firebase db.

Comment: So is it working now? If it is I will write it up as an answer so other people can also benefit from this.

Comment: @AndréKool Yes please, also to add on with the rules solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to filter data using the REST api you have to add `orderBy` to your parameters to specify what field you want to filter on. (It doesn't actually do anything for ordering on the client side) And in this case you have to combine it with `equalTo` as stated in [the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/retrieve-data#section-rest-filtering). The result will be this:

```
https://mydatabase.firebaseio.com/user.json?orderBy="Name"&equalTo="Alan"
```

In order to make this work you also need to [add an index](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/indexing-data) in your database rules like this:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "user": {
      ".indexOn": ["Name"]
    }
  }
}
```